# Running windows commands by java program

Tags: java, command

I want to run command

ipmsg.exe /MSG 192.168.0.8 "TEXT MESSAGE"

by a java program. Can anybody help me?

I am trying the following lines. But it is not working..

```
Runtime run_t = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process notify = run_t.exec("cmd /c ipmsg.exe /MSG 192.168.0.8 Hello");
```

PS:- My computer is connected to the computer with ip address 192.168.0.8 with LAN.

Comment: "it is not working" is *never* enough information. What's happening, compared with what you expected to happen? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Have you executed this command from a shell or CLI to see if it really works out of Java?

Comment: Actually i want to send text messages to computers connected with my computer using Lan. I am using IP Messenger tool for this. I want to run this tool by java program therefore i am typing command 
"ipmsg.exe /MSG  ipaddress text_message". But this command is not working when i am using it with java program

Comment: @user2087814 You still haven't told what the error or exception you get. Run your program again and paste whatever you see.

Comment: @asgs: yes, this command is working correctly when i am executing it from command prompt

Comment: If the command outputs something, you might need to read and flush the output or the process will block.

Comment: @asgs: i am not getting any error. But it is not sending my message to computer 192.168.0.8

Comment: In that case, you may have to read your program's OutputStream (which is the Java process' InputStream) and find out what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for better working with external processes. Also, always pass arguments as separate strings, apart from the command name.

Comment: But ip address is not a string. So how to pass it inside exec() or ProcessBuilder??

Comment: Whatever input you provide as part of a command (which includes the command name too) is treated as a String from Java perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You need two threads to capture the standal output or error output like this:

```
package demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class ExecDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nslookup google.com");
        Thread stdout = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread stderr = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        //
        stdout.start();
        stderr.start();
        //
        stdout.join();
        stderr.join();
        //
        p.waitFor();
    }

}
```

output (In Mac OS X):

```
Server:     192.168.6.1
Address:    192.168.6.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.31.113
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.31.138
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.31.139
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.31.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.31.101
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.31.102
```

Comment: +1 for snippets on reading the Process' Streams. @user2087814 You may have to try something similar to this like assylias hinted.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.. My program is now working correctly :)

Comment: @user2087814 you might want to explain what you did to make the program work, so that others can learn.